# One facet page (not solr) of users and block of rating based on count of entity referense fields (nodes) for each user

Tags: views, entities, rating, search

Drupal 7
for each user Example what i need:

I have views page with list of users (facet api (not solr)

Filter  1 = vendor (facet by taxonomy term)

Filter 2 = location (facet by taxonomy term)

Etc…

List of user

User 1 profile  : field vendor (term) | field location (term) | !  block of rating user 1 (count nodes (refense nodes by type) to current user (for example “complited project” which user made by vendor and location by current selected facet filters )

User2 profile : field vendor (term) | field location (term) | ! block of rating user 2 by current active filter

User3 profile : field vendor (term) | field location (term) | ! block of rating user 3 by current active filter

If I use page only with user list (without block of rating)  – it’s no problem but if I want use on the same page blocks with rating for each user - it’s big problem

For block of rating I tried to use field Global View field in which insert block with count of entity reference nodes (also tried use just value of reference field  (nodes) – it’s always show all value – not by active filter)

Solutions which I tried (not work as I want) for block of rating:

1. search api filter work only by unique field, situation looks like

Example  filter for vendors:

First indexed field for user: (field in search api index)

user -> user profile -> vendors

Second indexed field for nodes of current user (for count rating)

user-> user profile -> entity reference (node) -> vendor

in page list of user – if use only First filter (by user -> user profile -> vendors)  - > second indexed field (nodes) not work

it’s need two filter in same page (for first and second field – so I have duplicate of filter – but I need just one filter – by user profile -> vendor)

(may be exist way to insert  value from one filter to another and hide second filter but I don’t know how to do this)

2. I tried to use the same name of field (it’s not good for my project)

First indexed field (index of users)

User profile -> vendors

Second indexed field (index of nodes)

Node-> vendor

Now I can use one filter for user and block of rating in same time but -  if user has not vendor and in node of user have vendor  - > page empty  (because filter show term of user and node in same time – I need to show only terms of user -  not terms of nodes in filter to search by user)

3. I tried module Group for facet – but it’s not working
4. I tried to take tid from url in contextual filter  of block (usual block and facet block) (to get term of current selected facet filters value) – not work

Please help how to find solution?